# Migrating ZFS from using partitions to using the entire disk

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I have a simple ZFS setup that I've been running for a few years now. When I originally set it up, I created a number of partitions and created a zpool from a partition on each of my two drives, and used the others for booting etc..

Now however I have a separate drive for booting and everything else, so I just want to use the entire drives for my zpool. I recently replaced a drive, so I'm already doing that on one drive:

```
tank                        ONLINE       0     0     0
  mirror-0                  ONLINE       0     0     0
    ada2                    ONLINE       0     0     0
    ada1p4                  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

What I want to do now is to replace `ada1p4` with `ada1`, the question is, how do I do that? Is it as simple as `zpool replace tank ada1p4 ada1`, or is that a bad idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. BACKUP anything you care about... to something off this server.
2. Do the replacement

   ```
   zpool set autoexpand=on tank
   zpool offline tank ada1p4
   zpool replace tank ada1p4 ada1
   ```
3. Wait... and lots of it. Check status with `zpool status tank`
4. Turn off the autoexpand, `zpool set autoexpand=off tank`. It's a best practices thing mostly.

Comment: Is offline really necessary? I do not get what autoexpand is and why it is needed.

Comment: What does it matter if it's "really necessary" or not? The steps include best practices to prevent "oh sh*t" situations. The size of the disk and the size of the partition are different, that's what the "autoexpand" is for.

Comment: @ChrisS Okay, no offense. I did not realized the size change and you did not say. What's why I asked ;-)